# Tests becoming very long with configurations Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

been a while since I have been here and am just trying to re-familiarize myself with my test automation framework I have been working on.  Maybe a stupid question but I am going to throw it out there anyway as I think aloud.

Because I have introduced a config file which contains the path to an excel file(which contains test data) and implemented a basic excel reader to extract this data for testing I am finding that a great deal of my initial test is primarily taken up by all this set up.

For instance:

1. create an instance of a ReadPropertyFile class
2. Create an object of an ExcellDataConfig class and pass to it the location of the excel file from the config file
3. set the testcase id for this test to scan the excel file for where to start reading the data from the sheet - excel sheet contains markers
4. get the locations rol / col info from the sheet of all the interesting stuff i need for my test e.g. username / password, or some other data
5. open the browser
6. in the case of running a test on for multiple users set up a for loop that iterates through the excel sheet and logs in and then does the actual test.

Is a lot of configuration options but is there a simpler way?

I have a separate TestBase class which contains the login class and i thought to somehome move this user login info  stuff there but not sure if that is such a good idea.

I just don't want to get bogged down duplicating work does anyone have any high level suggestions?

Comment: Is it really necessary for you to use Excel? I keep my test data in Java properties (for simple storage) or Json format (for more complex data). It is loaded very quickly and integrates well with any IDE I know. For logging in: In most cases it is useful to put the login/logout code in a setup/teardown-method (use @Before, @After) of a base class, so any derived class will use it automatically.

Comment: Thanks @Würgspaß I will look into your suggestion for JSON file.

Comment: Ok, I added a code example, so I hope you will get the idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a compilable (but not fully coded) quick-and-dirty example how you could design a **base class for Selenium test classes**.   This follows the DRY principle (Don't Repeat Yourself).

The base class defines a login/logout method which would be called prior/after test execution of derived test classes.

Data is read from a Json file (based on javax.json) and used for **locating elements (using the keys) and entering data (using the values)**. You can easily expand the code to support handling of other elements or location strategies (css, xpath).

Note that this example is not performance-optimised. But it is quick enough for a start and you could adapt it to your needs (e.g. eager data loading in a static context).

```
package myproject;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.stream.JsonParser;
import javax.json.stream.JsonParser.Event;

import org.junit.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;

public class MyProjectBaseTest {    
    protected static WebDriver driver;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://myapp");
        login();
    }

    @After
    public void after() {
        logout();
    }

    private void login() {
        Map<String, String> data = readData("/path/to/testdata/login.json");

        Set<String> keys = data.keySet();
        for (String key : keys) {
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20L);
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(key)));
            final WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id(key));
            if ("input".equals(we.getTagName())) {
                we.clear();
                we.sendKeys(data.get(key));
            }
            //else if "button".equals(we.getTagName())
        }
    }

    private void logout() {
        //logout code ...
    }

    private Map<String, String> readData(String filename) {
        Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
        
        InputStream is = null;
        String key = null;        
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(filename);
            JsonParser parser = Json.createParser(is);
            while (parser.hasNext()) {
                Event e = parser.next();
                if (e == Event.KEY_NAME) {
                    key = parser.getString();
                }
                if (e == Event.VALUE_STRING) {
                    data.put(key, parser.getString());
                }
            }
            parser.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            //error handling
        }
        finally {
            //close is
        }
        
        return data;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

All this "setup work", you've described actually is pretty common stuff and it is how the [AAA pattern](http://wiki.c2.com/?ArrangeActAssert) really works:

> a pattern for arranging and formatting code in UnitTest methods

For advanced **Fixture** usage you could utilize the most suitable for your case [xUnit Setup pattern](http://xunitpatterns.com/Fixture%20Setup%20Patterns.html).

I totally agree with @Würgspaß's comment. What he is describing is called [Object Map](http://www.ontestautomation.com/building-and-using-an-object-repository-in-selenium-webdriver/) and I've used it heavily in the past 3 years with great success across multiple Automation projects.

I don't see in your scenario any usage of specific framework, so I would suggest that you pick some mature one, like [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) in combination with [Cucumber JVM](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/jvm). The last one will provide a [Context injection](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference/java-di), so you can get always clean step definition objects that can share context/state during the scenario run. And you will be able to reuse all the heavy setup just once and share it between all the tests. `I/O` operations are expensive and may cause issues in more complex cases, e.g. parallel execution of your tests.

As for the design of your code, you can find some of the [Selenium's Test design considerations](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/06_test_design_considerations.jsp) very useful, like the `CallWrappers`.

Comment: Thanks for providing some great links and suggestions @ekostadinov I will look into trying to figure out how to improve based on the materials you provided

Comment: @tarquin please remove the 'Thanks' comment. StackOverflow has clear policy of voting good and useful answers, you can also mark mine as 'Accepted'. This will help us keep your question clean :)